# I am using Interop.TDAPIOLELib.dll for QC ALM Integration But taking too much time for getting All Test Plan Tree Structure

Tags: vb.net, interop, hp-quality-center

I am using **Interop.TDAPIOLELib.dll** for **QC ALM 12** Integration and installed QcConnector.exe from tool link from QC ALM 12 on my 32 bit window machine.

I want to fetch all TestPlan with parent folder hierarchy . But its take too much time around **75 artifact of QC ALM** (included Test Plan and Folder) taking **1 minute 50 seconds**.

```
  Private Sub LoadQCTree()

    Dim rootNode As Object = Nothing

    _treeManager = CType(_qcConnection.TreeManager, TreeManager)

    Dim rootList As TDAPIOLELib.List = _treeManager.RootList

    Dim rNode = rootList.Item(1)

    rootNode = _treeManager.TreeRoot(rNode)

    Dim FolderList As List = rootNode.NewList()

    'Read sub node hierarchy...

    RecurseTree(CType(FolderList, List))

    ReadChildTestCases(rootNode)

 End Sub


  Private Sub RecurseTree(ByVal SubNodes As TDAPIOLELib.List)

    For Each itm As SysTreeNode In SubNodes
        Dim Description = CStr(itm.Description).Trim
        If Not Description = "" Then Description = ConvertPlain(Description).Trim
        AddNodeEntry(itm.Name, CStr(itm.NodeID), CStr(itm.Father.NodeID), "Folder", Description, Now, Now, "TestCase", "folder")

        Dim children = itm.NewList
        RecurseTree(CType(children, List))
        ReadChildTestCases(itm)

    Next

  End Sub

  Private Sub ReadChildTestCases(ByVal itm As SysTreeNode)

    Dim testFilter As TDFilter = CType(_testFactory.Filter, TDFilter)

    testFilter.Filter("TS_SUBJECT") = Chr(34) & itm.Path & Chr(34)


    Dim TestList As List = _testFactory.NewList(testFilter.Text)

    For Each test As Test In TestList
        Try
            Dim description As String = Convert.ToString(test.Field("TS_DESCRIPTION")).Trim
            If Not description = "" Then description = ConvertPlain(description).Trim
            Dim modifiedOn As Date = CDate(test.Field("TS_VTS"))
            Dim CreationDate As Date = CDate(test.Field("TS_CREATION_DATE"))
            modifiedOn = Date.SpecifyKind(modifiedOn, DateTimeKind.Local)
            CreationDate = Date.SpecifyKind(CreationDate, DateTimeKind.Local)

            Dim BaseId = test.Field("TS_BASE_TEST_ID")
            Dim type = test.Field("TS_TYPE")
            AddNodeEntry(test.Name, CStr(test.ID), CStr(itm.NodeID), "File", description, modifiedOn, CreationDate, "TestCase", type)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Do nothing..
            'Current node will skip from the tree hierarchy

        End Try
    Next
  End Sub
```

And also want to Fetch Requirements with folder hierarchy but its also taking to much time.

So , I'll try to improve performance using thread .

Thread 1 :  Load all Test Plan

Thread 2 :  Load all Requirement

and run parallel but i think is not supported parallel request. Because when i fetch requirement it takes **40 second (for 30 requirements)** but fetch both parallel taking **1 minute 15 second** for only requirements .

Please Help me to find out the way to how improve performance .

It is possible to get all test plan tree structure in one call.

Thanks

Comment: You can only get help from an expert that knows the product *really* well.  The odds that you'll find one here, especially with the current tags on the question, are zero.  Use the Hewlett Packard support forum to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all a project's requirements and tests then it is faster to use the connection object's factories with NewList(""). Something like this (this is just pseudo-code):

```
RequirementFactory factory = connection.RequirementFactory;
List reqs = factory.NewList(""); /* this is all a project's requirements */
```

Instead of walking the hierarchy and getting the reqs or tests for each folder.

Comment: Thanks @TheArtTrooper its very usefull for me using this i am able to get all requirement with folder.